# pandas.DataFrameで固定値列を追加したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

DataFrameがあった際に、固定の列をindex？の0から追加をしたいです。
言葉だとうまく説明できないため、疑似的なコードで記載いたします。

```
import pandas as pd
# 既存のDataFrame（実際にはそれなりの件数が存在）
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'hoge', 'hogehoge'], [2, 'huga', 'hugahuga'], [3, 'piyo', 'piyopiyo']])

#1, hoge, hogehoge
#2, huga, hugahuga
#3, piyo, piyopiyo

df.xxxx(['add1', 'add2', 'add3']) # ここを知りたいです。

# こういった形で固定値の列を複数列追加したい
#add1, add2, add3, 1, hoge, hogehoge
#add1, add2, add3, 2, huga, hugahuga
#add1, add2, add3, 3, piyo, piyopiyo
```

追加したいカラムは複数あるため、1つ１つ追加ではなく一括で追加できればと考えています。
（難しいのであれば追加したい列をforで回して追加していくになりますでしょうか？）

Comment: `pandas.concat()` を使って `pd.concat([*[pd.Series([x]*len(df)) for x in ['add1', 'add2', 'add3']], df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)` はどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

とりあえず何通りかを記載しましたので、お好きな方法をどうぞ
（カラム名は特に書き換えておりません）

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'hoge', 'hogehoge'],
     [2, 'huga', 'hugahuga'],
     [3, 'piyo', 'piyopiyo']])

# DataFrame.join() を使う
res = pd.DataFrame([['add1','add2','add3']]*len(df)).join(df, lsuffix='a')
#     0a    1a    2a  0     1         2
#0  add1  add2  add3  1  hoge  hogehoge
#1  add1  add2  add3  2  huga  hugahuga
#2  add1  add2  add3  3  piyo  piyopiyo

# これでも同じ
res = pd.DataFrame({0:'add1',1:'add2',2:'add3'}, index=df.index).join(df, lsuffix='a')
#     0a    1a    2a  0     1         2
#0  add1  add2  add3  1  hoge  hogehoge
#1  add1  add2  add3  2  huga  hugahuga
#2  add1  add2  add3  3  piyo  piyopiyo


# pandas.concat() を使う
res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([['add1','add2','add3']]*len(df)),df], axis=1)
#      0     1     2  0     1         2
#0  add1  add2  add3  1  hoge  hogehoge
#1  add1  add2  add3  2  huga  hugahuga
#2  add1  add2  add3  3  piyo  piyopiyo


# DataFrame.assign() を使い列を追加、その後列を並び替える
res=df.assign(a='add1',b='add2',c='add3')
res = res.loc[:,res.columns[3:].append(res.columns[:3])]
#      a     b     c  0     1         2
#0  add1  add2  add3  1  hoge  hogehoge
#1  add1  add2  add3  2  huga  hugahuga
#2  add1  add2  add3  3  piyo  piyopiyo

# ループにて列を追加、その後列を並び替える（元のDataFrameを書き換え）
df.columns += 3 #挿入分 列番号を空ける
for i,val in enumerate(['add1', 'add2', 'add3']):
    df[i] = val
res = df.sort_index(axis=1)
#      0     1     2  3     4         5
#0  add1  add2  add3  1  hoge  hogehoge
#1  add1  add2  add3  2  huga  hugahuga
#2  add1  add2  add3  3  piyo  piyopiyo
```

Answer (score 0):

追加する列名を指定して代入します。下記の例では列名を適当にしているため、適宜変更してください。

```
df[3] = "add1"
df[4] = "add2"
df[5] = "add3"
```